# Label 'edited' in flag dashboard / waffle bar not vertically aligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard

The flag dashboard and the 'waffle bar' have some labels which indicate potentially useful information about a flagged post (or a post for which one of the comments has been flagged). In the screenshots below, 'edited' (which indicates it has been edited after the flag) and '0 answers'. The 'edited' label is not centered vertically, because it does not have the `va-baseline` class, which makes it look a little awkward:

[image]
[image]

It could be that other labels have this problem as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this and the fix should be live already. Thanks for the heads up!